# Unable to start Glass Fish 4.0 on time in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

<del>This is my Java Server Code. Just receiving message from client and echoing the message back. I am using WebSocket.</del>

```
package pack.exp;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/serverendpointdemo")
public class EchoServer 
{
    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen()
    {
        System.out.println("Client is now Connected...");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage(String Message)
    {
       System.out.println("Message receive From Client... " + Message);
       String replyMsg= "Echo from Server..." + Message;
       System.out.println("Message sent to Client... " + Message);
       return replyMsg;
    }

     @OnClose
     public void handleClose()
     {
        System.out.println("Client is now Disconnected...");
      }

   @OnError
   public void handleError(Throwable t)
   {
        t.printStackTrace();
   }
 }

 The client is in Java Script, The client is sending the message and receiving the echo     
 from the server.

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
 <input id="textMessage" type= "text">
 <input onclick= "sendMessage"; value= "Send Message" type="button">
 </form>

 <br>
 <textarea id= "messageTextArea" rows="80" cols="50"></textarea>

     <script type="text/javascript">
  var webSoc= new 
      WebSocket("ws//localhost:8080/WSocEcho/serverendpointdemo");
  var messageTextArea= document.getElementById("messageTextArea");

   webSoc.onopen= function(message) 
   {
      processOpen(message;)
    };

   webSoc.onmessage= function(message) 
   {
      processMessage(message;)
   };

   webSoc.onclose= function(message)
   {
       processClose(message);  
    }

    webSoc.onerror(Message)
    {
        processError(message);
     }

function processOpen(message)
{
    messageTextArea.value= "Server Connect..." + "\n";
}

function processMessage(message)
{
    messageTextArea.value= "Recieve from Server..." + message.data + 
                  "\n";
}

function processClose(message)
{
    webSoc.send("Client Disconnected...");
    messageTextArea.value+= "Server Disconnect..." + "\n";
}

function processOpen(message)
{
    messageTextArea.value+= "Error..." + "\n";
}

function sendMessage()
{
    webSoc.send(textMessage.value); 
    messageTextArea.value+= "Sent to Server... " + textMessage.value + 
                  "\n";
    textMessage.value("");
}
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am using Glass Fish 4.0 and Eclipse Juno. But when I am <del>running</del> starting the <del>code on</del> server, it is taking like 7-8 minutes to start the `Glass Fish` and after that also getting this error

> Unable to start server on time
>      java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Comment: have you found the solution?